# PDF of difference in random variables via convolution

Tags: probability, convolution, signal-processing

*See the figure for reference:*

[image]

$f_i$ and $f_{i+1}$ are unobserved times of events, while $y_i$ and $y_{i+1}$ are observed times of subsequent events.
We'd like to recover the distribution of $f_{i+1} - f_i \sim G(\tau)$, but we've only observed
$y_{i+1} - y_i \sim S(\tau)$, and
$y_i - f_i \sim H(\tau)$.
Notably, we have parametric definitions of $S(\tau)$ and $H(\tau)$,
not actual observations of $y_i$, $f_i$, etc.

**Is this the correct way to recover $G(\tau)$ ?**

\begin{aligned}
y_{i+1} - y_i &\sim \big(f_{i+1} + H(\tau)\big) - \big(f_i + H(\tau)\big)\\
&\sim \big(f_i + G(\tau) + H(\tau)\big) - \big(f_i + H(\tau)\big)\\
&\sim G(\tau) + H(\tau) - H(\tau)
\end{aligned}
Since the PDF of a sum of random variables is the convolution of their PDFs
([more info](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331973)),
then:
\begin{aligned}
  S(\tau) &= G(\tau) * H(\tau) * H(-\tau)\\
  G(\tau) &= \big( S(\tau) *^{-1} H(\tau) \big) *^{-1} H(-\tau)
\end{aligned}
where $*$ is convolution, and $*^{-1}$ is deconvolution.
I don't need an exact solution, so kindly disregard any required deconvolution sorcery.

**In particular, I negated $\tau$ in the 2nd $H$ by intuition, but is that correct?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\R{\mathbb{R}}$For any random variable $X$ with a p.d.f. $f_X$, since$$
P(-X \leqslant a) = P(X \geqslant -a) = \int_{-a}^{+∞} f_X(x)\,\d x = \int_{-∞}^a f_X(-y) \,\d y,\quad\forall a \in \R
$$
then $f_{-X}(a) = f_X(-a)$ for $a \in \R$.

Now, note that$$
y_{i + 1} - y_i = (f_{i + 1} - f_i) + (y_{i + 1} - f_{i + 1}) - (y_i - f_i).
$$
If $f_{i + 1} - f_i, y_{i + 1} - f_{i + 1}, y_i - f_i$ are independent, then\begin{align*}
S(a) &= f_{y_{i + 1} - y_i}(a) = f_{f_{i + 1} - f_i}(a) * f_{y_{i + 1} - f_{i + 1}}(a) * f_{-(y_i - f_i)}(a)\\
&= f_{f_{i + 1} - f_i}(a) * f_{y_{i + 1} - f_{i + 1}}(a) * f_{y_i - f_i}(-a)\\
&= G(a) * H(a) * H(-a),
\end{align*}
and$$
G(a) = (S(a) *^{-1} H(-a)) *^{-1} H(a) = (S(a) *^{-1} H(a)) *^{-1} H(-a).
$$

Comment: Perfect -- thank you!